# Tomar los datos de un input, fijarse si algun valor coincide, y si coincide, mostrar los valores que coinciden en cierto formato

Tags: javascript, html5, dom, events

Tengo que hacer una búsqueda de productos. Donde, mediante un `input`, yo ingreso el valor, y me tiene que mostrar los productos que cumplen con el dato ingresado por el `input`. Por ejemplo, yo tengo un array de 2 productos. Los productos son: 75 y 22. Entonces cuando yo ingrese el numero 75, que el 22 se oculte y que se vea solo el 22. Esto tiene que funcionar tanto con el id del producto, como con la descripción de este.
Mi código es este

```js
class Producto {
    constructor(id, descripcion,precio) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
}
let productos = [];

productos.push(new Producto("751100", "Manija", 5000));
productos.push(new Producto("851100", "Manija", 5000));
productos.push(new Producto("751200", "Manija", 5000));
productos.push(new Producto("753100", "Manija", 5000));

let section = document.querySelector('.tiendaOnline.row.separar.container-fluid');

for (const producto of productos) {
    let article = document.createElement("article");
    article.className = "col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 carta";
    article.innerHTML = `   <img src="../imagenes/ft-nosotros.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Imagen de Producto">
                            <div>
                            
                            <h3 class="codigo">${producto.id}</h3>
                            <p class="descripcion">${producto.descripcion}</p>
                            <p class="precio">$${producto.precio}</p>
                            
    
                                <div>
                                    <div class="btnCompra">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-cart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
                            </svg>
                                    <a href="" data-id="${producto.id}" class="btn-add">Agregar al Carrito</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<a href="" id="detalles${producto.id}" class="btnDetalles">Ver detalles</a>-->
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
   
    section.appendChild(article);
}
//Búsqueda
let busqueda = document.getElementById("inputBusqueda").value;

const filtroBusqueda = (id) => {
    if (busqueda !== "") {
        return resultado = productos.find(producto => producto.id == id);
        
    }
}
filtroBusqueda(busqueda);
```

```html
<div class="inputIcon col col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
  </svg>
  <input type="text" class="inputBusqueda" id="inputBusqueda" placeholder="Buscá productos, marcas y más">

</div>
<section class="tiendaOnline row separar container-fluid">

</section>
```

La búsqueda creo está hecha, porque cuando puse un `alert` para probar, no mostraba ningún valor, pero no puedo hacer que se oculten o se muestren productos dependiendo del criterio de búsqueda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funciona porque estás tomando el valor al cargar la página y no consideras el momento en que el usuario teclea algo en el campo:

```
// Búsqueda - Simplemente tomas el valor
let busqueda = document.getElementById("inputBusqueda").value;

const filtroBusqueda = (id) => {
    if (busqueda !== "") {
        // .find devuelve solo el primer elemento que cumple la condición
        return resultado = productos.find(producto => producto.id == id);
        
    }
}
// Realizas la búsqueda, pero no usas el resultado
filtroBusqueda(busqueda);
```

Solo estás seleccionando un producto que coincida con el valor del campo, pero no lo usas posteriormente y, además, deberías simplemente mostrar el HTML de los productos que coinciden y ocultar los demás, pero basado en acciones del usuario al teclear en el campo de búsqueda.

Para lograrlo, te recomiendo [escuchar un evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), de preferencia `input`, para que se ejecute con cualquier cambio realizado en el campo de búsqueda.

```js
class Producto {
    constructor(id, descripcion,precio) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
}
let productos = [];

productos.push(new Producto("751100", "Manija", 5000));
productos.push(new Producto("851100", "Manija", 5000));
productos.push(new Producto("751200", "Manija", 5000));
productos.push(new Producto("753100", "Manija", 5000));

let section = document.querySelector('.tiendaOnline.row.separar.container-fluid');

for (const producto of productos) {
    let article = document.createElement("article");
    article.className = "col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 carta";
    article.innerHTML = `   <img src="../imagenes/ft-nosotros.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Imagen de Producto">
                            <div>
                            
                            <h3 class="codigo">${producto.id}</h3>
                            <p class="descripcion">${producto.descripcion}</p>
                            <p class="precio">$${producto.precio}</p>
                            
    
                                <div>
                                    <div class="btnCompra">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-cart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
                            </svg>
                                    <a href="" data-id="${producto.id}" class="btn-add">Agregar al Carrito</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<a href="" id="detalles${producto.id}" class="btnDetalles">Ver detalles</a>-->
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
   
    section.appendChild(article);
}
// Declarar una variable para acceder al campo
let busqueda = document.querySelector('#inputBusqueda');
// Asignar evento
busqueda.addEventListener('input', e => {
    // Obtener valor del campo, ignorando espacios en los extremos
    let buscar = busqueda.value.trim();
    // Obtener todos los productos (HTML, no el arreglo) por clase
    let prodHtml = document.querySelectorAll('.carta');
    // Recorrer todos los elementos
    prodHtml.forEach(article => {
        // Buscar ID de producto
        let id = article.querySelector('.codigo').textContent;
        // Mostrar si la búsqueda es cadena vacía o si ID de producto incluye la cadena
        if(buscar == '' || id.includes(buscar)) {
            article.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            // No coincide la búsqueda, ocultar
            article.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="inputIcon col col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
  </svg>
  <input type="text" class="inputBusqueda" id="inputBusqueda" placeholder="Buscá productos, marcas y más">

</div>
<section class="tiendaOnline row separar container-fluid">

</section>
```

Comment: Te hago una pregunta, conocés si este método funciona para grandes cantidades de datos o sólo funciona para pequeñas cantidades de datos?

Comment: @Inkinvissible, si tienes muchos productos, lo mejor sería cargarlos desde una base de datos, con paginación y AJAX; pero si se pueden mostrar todos en la página, no deberías tener problemas, excepto por el tiempo que tarden en aplicarse los cambios.

Comment: Claro! Muchas Gracias!